# Using Activity vs View in Android for eBook type App

Tags: android, view, android-activity

Im a beginning Android developer with a few simple apps under my belt.  I'd like to create a choose-your-own-adventure style eBook.  Each page will have some text and two-buttons at the bottom.  Example:  There's a fork in the road.  The buttons would be something like Go Left or Go Right.  Selecting one of the buttons takes you to the next page with new choices(buttons) There will be about 100 "pages" total.

My question is this:  **Is it better to display each page in a new Activity or do I continually inflate views (like a scrollView)**?

Ive done quite a bit of googling on this and ended up more confused.

Answer (score 1):

An activity has the advantage of an automatic history, but you probably don't want to have a history. Therefore, I would use one activity which updates its contents. Then, you won't have to pass the game state through the intents.